# Plotting 1D Quadratic FEM Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, finite-element-method

I am solving an ODE $$ u''= -x^2 $$ from $0\leq x \leq 1$, using Dirichlet boundary conditions; 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
u(0)&=0 \\ u(1)&= 0.01
\end{array}  
\right.
$$
using 1D quadratic FEM in MATLAB. I am using Lagrange quadratic interpolation as my basis functions. 
I know in 1D quadratic fem, each element has three nodes, $n$ elements and $2n+1$ nodes. I am solving for $u$ and in the end I am getting solution values for each node.

Now I want to plot these solution points with respect to Nodes over the analytical solution. I am using plot(Nod,u) where Nod is the number of nodes and u is the solution data values for each node, MATLAB is making straight lines instead of making curves. 
Does any body knows how to make curve using Nodes and solution points, so my solution looks like quadratic instead of linear?
thanks!

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I tried adding it, but it is too long...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to plot. Certainly your code would help us understand what you want. Are you trying to plot the solution in a determined position as a function of the number of nodes, ie, `plot(no_of_nodes,u)`? Or are you trying to plot the solution `u` as a function of the independent variable `x`, ie, `plot(x,u)`?

Comment: I am trying to plot the solution in a determined position as a function of the number of nodes.

Comment: Now, simple plot was not working, so I used a for loop. here is the code           
 c = zeros(3,1);
d = zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:1:nE
    c(1,1) = Nod(2*(i-1)+1);
    c(2,1) = Nod(2*(i-1)+2);
    c(3,1) = Nod(2*(i-1)+3);
    d(1,1) = u(2*(i-1)+1);
    d(2,1) = u(2*(i-1)+2);
    d(3,1) = u(2*(i-1)+3);
    f= fit(c,d,'poly2');
    plot(f,c,d,'dr');
    
    hold on;
 end